# XMLHttpRequest cannot load no Vue js

Tags: javascript, api, rest, http, vue.js

***Meu app.vue***

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ titulo }}</h1>
        <li v-for="usuario of usuarios">

        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {

    },
    created() {
        //componente
        let promisse =  this.$http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/', { headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }});

        console.log(promisse);
        promisse.then(res => alert(res));

    }
}
</script>
```

***Meu main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
//importando o vue-rsource
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

//Usando globalmente o vue-resource
Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Esta dando esse erro

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/. Request
>   header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. localhost/:1
>   Uncaught (in promise) Response {url: "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
>   ok: false, status: 0, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse tipo de erro ocorre por conta do CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). Os navegadores costumam fazer uma requisição é enviada do tipo OPTIONS e o servidor vai responder se o tipo de requisição que se pretende fazer (no seu caso um GET) está liberada ou não pra origem (sua aplicação).

Caso a API que você esteja consumindo seja sua, vai ser necessário configurar o CORS nela, definindo a sua aplicação como parte do conjunto que poderá acessar os recursos da mesma.

Caso você possua mais dúvidas, pesquise mais um pouco sobre CORS e suas configurações (variam de plataforma para plataforma somente na implementação, o conceitual é o mesmo).